# How to multiply items in an array for example 4 lots of [ 1 .. 10 ] in F#

Tags: arrays, list, f#

I am trying to put a deck of cards (Blackjack) into an array or list. I have seen this done before but can't remember the syntax and can't find it anywhere.

I need something like this `let list = [ 1 .. 10; 10; 10; 10 ] * 4`, but of course this doesn't work. If anybody could help I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You can use `Seq.allPairs`, have a look at [`newDeck()`](https://github.com/mindems/PlayingFs.Cards/blob/master/PlayingFs/Cards.fs).

Comment: Your line of code has two problems. 1. `[ 1 .. 10; 10; 10; 10 ]` is not defined. 2. a list cannot be multiplied by an integer. You can use `[1..10] @ [1..10] @ [1 .. 10] @ [1::10]` or `[ for i = 1 to 4 do yield! [1 .. 10] ]`. However I believe a better answer is that for absolute beginners it's better to learn from books and that you haven't yet reached the level where you can benefit from StackOverflow questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the exact syntax you're after...

Ideally you want a list for suits and a list for cards and then you create a [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), and it is probably easiest to store each card in the deck in a tuple of `number, suit`

```
let cards = [1..10]
let suits = [1..4]

let deck = seq { 
    for card in cards do //cards could just be [1..10]
        for suit in suits do //suits could be too
            yield card, suit }

//Show the answer
printfn "%A" (deck |> Seq.toList)
```

Usually a suit would be a Discriminated Union and you could map the numbers:

```ml
type Suit = 
| Hearts
| Spades
| Diamonds
| Clubs

let toSuit suit =
    match suit with
    | 1 -> Hearts
    | 2 -> Spades
    | 3 -> Diamonds
    | 4 -> Clubs
```

and change `yield card, suit }` to `yield card, toSuit suit }`

You could do the same with the cards to by having a DU from Ace -> King. I'll leave that as an exercise for you ;)

Finally, if you are after a generic function to this, you could write something like this - I don't recall this been in FSharp.Core, but I may be wrong.

```ml
let multiplyList xs by = seq {
    for x in xs do
        for y in [1..by] do 
            yield x, y }

let deck = multiplyList cards 4 |> Seq.toList
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you stated what language you are using, because the answer
may be different. I think you are looking for an array of array. You'll like need a bunch of arrays
to keep track of the card rank, suit, rank value, and whether it has been played, not played, or whatever you'd like. So you need something like:

```
ranks = ['A', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K']
rankValues = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
suits = [ 'spades', 'hearts', 'clubs', 'diamonds' ]

deck = [[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
card = [suit, rank]

deck [suit][rank] = true
deck [suit][rank] = false
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the tags of the question are usually used to specify what language the OP is using. This question is tagged `f#`, so the OP is looking for an answer in the F# language. Your answer looks like it's using Python, so it's not a correct answer for this question.